# strange issue div block not going back up after jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, joomla

Here I made this page with jQuery - http://peterhay.com/Fluxx/people

It works fine in ANY browser or device beside Google Chrome..

first row of pictures work ok but any other row (second or third etc..) doesn't go up after jQuery "detail_block" div is getting "display: none" styling... please check the page with Google Chrome and see for yourself.

CLICK on any picture from the second or third row and click again for the "detail_block" get's "hidden" and the row below will not come up... if you click on any image of the FIRST row everything works correctly..

Can somebody please help me with this I can't understand what is wrong... and it works fine in any other browser...

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I see four rows and five columns of pictures using Google Chrome Version 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit).

Comment: This is a coment, not an answer.

Comment: I know that )) that is how it should be, but press on any pictures from the second or third row and the row will not come back to top after "detail_block" is hidden..

Comment: @alirezasafian You're right, but I cannot comment without 50 rep. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexandruVlas I see what you mean now. You should specify that the problem is when you click on an image. Are you using the jQuery .slideUp method or something else? Can you post the code that is being enacted on the div?

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.customer_wrap .custom_item').on('click', function (evt) {

    var $button = jQuery(this);

    var $tr = $button.closest('div');

    var $div = $tr.find('.detail_block');

    jQuery('.detail_block').not($div).slideUp(); 

    $div.slideToggle();

    jQuery('.customer_wrap').toggleClass('opened');

});`

Comment: `jQuery('.detail_block').not($div).slideUp();`
`$div.slideToggle();`

Am I mistaken, or are these two lines essentially trying to do the same thing?

Comment: nope, one is hiding the current div, other is showing the clicked one.

Comment: I've tried to recreate the issue as best as I could but without diving in to your code I can't seem to figure it out. I'm sorry. I really hope you figure it out.